# Is there a other way to reset fields

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a reset spreadsheet function to clear the spreadsheet.
Now i use loops to define the values for each column. `'Dikte'` Needs to be set to `6`. And the first column needs to be false. `clearContent` clears everything. Is there a nicer way?

```
  var values = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    values.push([false,'','','','','6','0'])
  }
  var oldoak_data = SS.getRangeByName('oldoak_data').setValues(values);
```

[image: Product table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

**Solution 1:**

- You could get rid of the `for` loop by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This will give you some boost in performance since `map` is faster than the regular loops.
- Generally, since this approach overwrites the previous values, it is a good idea to clear the content before we set the new values.

**Solution 2:**

- Another idea would be to define a sheet object by its name. In my case `Sheet1`. Clear only the desired range, `'A2:E13'` and set the values of the other two columns to `6` and `0` respectively. Not sure if this approach is faster, but it could be more efficient.

---

### Solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
function resetFields() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rng = SS.getRangeByName('oldoak_data');
  const values = rng.getValues().map(r=>[false,'','','','','6','0'])
  rng.clearContent();
  rng.setValues(values);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
function resetFields() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const SH = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rngClear = SH.getRange('A2:E13');
  rngClear.clearContent();
  SH.getRange('F2:F13').setValue(6);
  SH.getRange('G2:G13').setValue(0);
}
```

**Example sheet for Solution 2:**

[image: example]

Comment: Solution 1, is for me the best approach. Solution 2, when I add a new row before the header columns. The relative reference e.g (A1:A10) is changed. That's why I use named ranges.